# expandtab / noexpandtab toggles by itself in Neovim

Tags: neovim, tab-characters

I have this issue where `noexpandtab` turns itself on after a while. Tried to describe it here and in the [Github Issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6561) because I am not 100% sure this is a legit bug.

For a long time, I have disregarded this thinking it is some plugin acting up. But then a friend who uses fairly minimalistic Neovim setup shared his frustration for the same behaviour.

It goes like this — you go about your work day and at some point in time it starts using tabs instead of spaces in all files. So I have to issue

```
:set et
:retab
```

To get the current file back on track, but the problem is the new `noexpandtab` setting becomes  "global" after that, so in the end I just restart Neovim. It might, of course, be a faulty plugin, but if this is actually a bug then more people should have been experiencing it.

The list of plugins that are common between our configurations:

```
AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim
AndrewRadev/vim-eco
Shougo/deoplete.nvim
Xuyuanp/nerdtree-git-plugin
airblade/vim-gitgutter
junegunn/fzf
kana/vim-textobj-user
kchmck/vim-coffee-script
mtscout6/vim-cjsx
mxw/vim-jsx
scrooloose/nerdtree
tpope/vim-abolish
tpope/vim-dispatch
tpope/vim-fugitive
tpope/vim-repeat
tpope/vim-surround
vim-airline/vim-airline
vim-airline/vim-airline-themes
vim-ruby/vim-ruby
```

Comment: Are you using plugins? If so which ones?

Comment: if this happens again, issue this command `:verbose set et?`

Comment: Keeping an eye on this is a little bit difficult, because one always has to look up the current state of the github issue too.

Comment: It's probably something doing `set expandtab` instead of `setlocal expandtab`. Either something you added in your vimrc file yourself, or something from a bad plugin. With `:verbose set et?` you can see where it was last set. You can also try following the steps in [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51)

Comment: Also, posting a question like this in two places at the same time isn't really a great thing to do. I see Justin already asked you some questions in the GitHub repo. Repeating exactly the same here is pretty much a waste of time of the community at large.

Comment: Which one do you think I should close?